# Error: IAsyncEnumerable cannot be used for parameter of type IEnumerable on Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asynchronous, linq-method-syntax

I've got these two LINQ expressions. I'm using Entity Framework. The only difference is the position of the items on the list of CardIds.

The first example returns the AdditionalCards that comes from "MemberAdditionalCards" first and then it adds the Card that is stored on the Members table.

The second example does the opposite, gets first the Card that is stored on the Members table and then the AdditionalCards that comes from "MembersAdditionalCards".

First LINQ:

```
            members = await _context.Members
                .Where(s => EF.Functions.Like(s.FirstNames, searchTerm))
                .Select(s => new Members
                {
                    Id = s.Id,
                    CardIds = s.MemberAdditionalCards
                        .Select(m => new AdditionalCard
                        {
                            CardId = m.CardId
                        })
                        .Union(new List<AdditionalCard>
                        {
                            new AdditionalCard
                            {
                                CardId = s.CardId
                            }
                        })
                        .ToList()
                })
                .AsNoTracking()
                .ToListAsync();
```

Second LINQ:

```
            members = await _context.Members
                .Where(s => EF.Functions.Like(s.FirstNames, searchTerm))
                .Select(s => new Members
                {
                    Id = s.Id,
                    CardIds = new List<AdditionalCard>
                    {
                        new AdditionalCard
                        {
                            CardId = s.CardId
                        }
                    }
                    .Union(s.MemberAdditionalCards
                        .Select(a => new AdditionalCard
                        {
                            CardId = a.CardId
                        }))
                    .ToList()
                })
                .AsNoTracking()
                .ToListAsync();
```

With the Second LINQ I've got an error:

[image: Error]

The first LINQ expression works fine but is not how I want to have the items on the list result.

With the Second LINQ expression: if I remove the "await" keyword from the second expression and in the end I do ToList() rather than ToListAsync() it works just fine. I do understand the issue is the async execution. But how can I make the last bit to be executed as async and why that issue doesn't happen with the First LINQ expression?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's complaining about this part:

```
.Union(s.MemberAdditionalCards
    .Select(a => new AdditionalCard
    {
        CardId = a.CardId
    }))
```

Since you're doing a `Union` on a `List<T>` (which is `IEnumerable`), then `Union` will only accept an `IEnumerable` as a parameter. But `s.MemberAdditionalCards.Select()` returns `IAsyncEnumerable`.

I'm not sure if it will like the `await` inside the Linq expression, so if it doesn't, then remove the `await` and change `ToListAsync()` to `ToList()`:

```
.Union(await s.MemberAdditionalCards
    .Select(a => new AdditionalCard
    {
        CardId = a.CardId
    }).ToListAsync())
```

I'm not sure what the resulting SQL will look like. Someone might have a better idea.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried the "await" inside the LINQ and It didn't like it. The .ToListAsync() doesn't come up since I'm not awaiting I think

Answer (score 0):

If you want the linq to be resolved in a single query you better remove all .ToList() calls within the select expression.

Try this:

```
members = await _context.Members
    .Where(s => EF.Functions.Like(s.FirstNames, searchTerm))
    .Select(s => new Members
    {
        Id = s.Id,
        CardIds = new List<AdditionalCard>
        {
            new AdditionalCard
            {
                CardId = s.CardId
            }
        }
        .Union(s.MemberAdditionalCards
            .Select(a => new AdditionalCard
            {
                CardId = a.CardId
            }))
    })
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Tried that as well and no luck. Same error was displayed